# Generate adjacency matrix from survey output

Tags: r, igraph, social-networking

I am trying to pull data from Excel in the form:

| Survey Respondents | Abby | Brandon | Jane | Mary | Pat |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Jane | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| Pat | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 |

Where 1 represents that the survey respondent knows the person in the column and zero represents that the survey respondent does not know the person in the column.

And I want to create two matrices that would have the form (where the numbers represent people)

|  | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 2 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 3 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| 4 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 5 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 |

And

| ID | NAME |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Abby |
| 2 | Brandon |
| 3 | Jane |
| 4 | Mary |
| 5 | Pat |

I've done this in Matlab, but since the network analysis is done in R, I'd rather do it all in R.

I am brand new to R, so I tried to do this by creating a new matrix from the starting matrix but was having trouble with matrix dimensions. And was unsure how to include the 0 and 1 data in addition to just creating the row and column labels.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to look at network/graph data, the `igraph` package can help. Here's how you could use it after transforming your data

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(igraph)

#sample data
dd <- data.frame(
  SurveyRespondents = c("Jane", "Pat"), 
    Abby = 1:0, Brandon = c(0L, 0L), Jane = 0:1, 
    Mary = c(1L, 1L), Pat = c(0L, 0L))

people <- sort(unique(c(dd$SurveyRespondents, names(dd)[-1])))
dd %>% 
  pivot_longer(-SurveyRespondents) %>% 
  filter(value==1) %>% 
  select(-value) %>% 
  graph_from_data_frame(., directed=FALSE, vertices = people) %>% 
  as_adjacency_matrix()

#         Abby Brandon Jane Mary Pat
# Abby       .       .    1    .   .
# Brandon    .       .    .    .   .
# Jane       1       .    .    1   1
# Mary       .       .    1    .   1
# Pat        .       .    1    1   .
```

`igraph` also makes it easy to plot the data
[image]

Answer (score 2):

## Base R

You can use the following base R option

```
v <- as.matrix(df[-1][match(names(df)[-1], df$SurveyRespondents), ])
u <- `rownames<-`(replace(v, is.na(v), 0), colnames(v))
pmax(u, t(u))
```

and you will obtain

```
        Abby Brandon Jane Mary Pat
Abby       0       0    1    0   0
Brandon    0       0    0    0   0
Jane       1       0    0    1   1
Mary       0       0    1    0   1
Pat        0       0    1    1   0
```

---

## igraph

With `igraph`, we can try

```
`row.names<-`(as.matrix(df[-1]), df$SurveyRespondents) %>%
    as.data.frame.table() %>%
    filter(Freq > 0) %>%
    graph_from_data_frame(directed = FALSE, vertices = names(df)[-1]) %>%
    as_adjacency_matrix(sparse = FALSE)
```

which gives

```
        Abby Brandon Jane Mary Pat
Abby       0       0    1    0   0
Brandon    0       0    0    0   0
Jane       1       0    0    1   1
Mary       0       0    1    0   1
Pat        0       0    1    1   0
```

Comment: Updated to non-deprecated names, hope you don't mind.

Comment: @Szabolcs haha, definitely no problem. I am glad that you keep my knowledge up-to-date :)